# Powershell: Anonymous LDAP query over SSL to non-Microsoft (?) server

Tags: powershell, ssl, ldap

I am trying to query an LDAP server via SSL using Powershell v4. The server is in a trusted domain.

-The server name is *xxx.xxx.intranet*

-Using the server name and port 636, I can connect to and query the server using *JXplorer* and *LDAPAdmin*

-When I query the server without a search base, it returns schema information containing "vendorName=Sun Microsystems" "vendorVersion=Directory Proxy Server 11.1.1.7.1", so I'm guessing I'm not talking to a MS machine

-I'm trying to use *System.DirectoryServices.Protocols* to query, since this seems to be a vendor-independent way to do it with Powershell - right?

-Right now, I'm stuck with this:

```
Find-LdapObject -SearchFilter:"(attributeOrigin=HR)" -LdapServer:"xxx.xxx.intranet:636" -searchBase "ou=People,o=Company"
```

This returns the following error:

```
The Distinguished Name Contains Invalid Syntax
```

Next, I tried to define the LDAP Server in a variable:

```
$ldapSrv=new-object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection(new-object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapDirectoryIdentifier(xxx.xxx.intranet, 636))
```

Then, set the auth type to 'basic' using - ugly but seems to work:

```
$ldapSrv.AuthType = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType
```

This is what I end up with:

```
The LDAP server is unavailable
```

Help is appreciated.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Is the LDAP server certificate trusted by your computer? `LdapConnection` only verifies against installed certificate authorities.
(Also to future readers: Using PowerShell Core 7.1+ should give more specific error messages since it's based on .NET 5+.)